# Set Multer object key in node.js on the fly

Tags: node.js, express, multer-s3

I have node express routes, where I need to set a aws bucket name in a Multer Object.

When the users get logged in my app, I have an API to get the correct bucket name to user.
I call that API in a middleware to all routes and I set req.folder_do_bucket='XXXX' from API result.

After that, when the user access others routes such as below, I need to set the bucket in the Multer Object. But, my problem is that "req" is not available to set it in the Multer.

Maybe I can create the multer object into the route, but I am not sure if this is a better solution, because I will have to do it in all routes(get, post....)

How could I solve it?

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

const storageImagemClienteS3 = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: req.folder_do_bucket, // AWS_BUCKET_NAME -->Here is my problem, req is not available  here
  contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
  acl: "public-read",
  key: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName =
      `${req.conta}/clientes/cliente-${req.params.id}/imagens/` +
      file.originalname;
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});
console.log(storageImagemClienteS3);
const uploadImagemClienteS3 = multer({
  storage: storageImagemClienteS3,
  limits: { fileSize: MAX_SIZE },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileTypeImage(file, cb);
  },
}).single("file");

router.post("/upload/:id", function (req, res) {
  if (!req.params.id || req.params.id == "undefined") {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ message: "Um erro ocorreu selecionando cliente" });
  }
  uploadImagemClienteS3(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      ....
    } else {
       ......    
       }
  });
});
```